# Parallel processing using TPL in windows service

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library

I have a windows service which is consuming a messaging system to fetch messages. I have also created a callback mechanism with the help of Timer class which helps me to check the message after some fixed time to fetch and process. Previously, the service is processing the message one by one. But I want after the message arrives the processing mechanism to execute in parallel. So if the first message arrived it should go for processing on one task and even if the processing is not finished for the first message still after the interval time configured using the callback method (callback is working now) next message should be picked and processed on a different task.

Below is my code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Subsriber<Message> subsriber = new Subsriber<Message>()
    {
       Interval = 1000
    };

    subsriber.Callback(Process, m => m != null);
});

public static void Process(Message message)
{
  if (message != null)
  {
     // Processing logic
  }
 else
 {

 }
}
```

But using the Task Factory I am not able to control the number of tasks in parallel so in my case I want to configure the number of tasks on which messages will run on the availability of the tasks?

---

Update:
Updated my above code to add multiple tasks

Below is the code:

```
         private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                int taskCount = 5;
                Task.Factory.StartNewAsync(() =>
                {
                   Subscriber<Message> consumer = new 
                   Subcriber<Message>()
                   {
                       Interval = 1000
                    };

                   consumer.CallBack(Process, msg => msg!= 
                   null);
                 }, taskCount);
                Console.ReadLine();
              }
             catch (Exception e)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            public static void StartNewAsync(this TaskFactory 
            target, Action action, int taskCount)
           {
                 var tasks = new Task[taskCount];
                 for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
                 {
                      tasks[i] = target.StartNew(action);
                 }
             }

             public static void Process(Message message)
            {
                 if (message != null)
                {

                 }
                else
                { }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Your last sentence is a little confusing for me, but do you mean -  you only want to have e.g. a max of 5 tasks running at any point, and keep track of what tasks are running?

Comment: Not specifically 5 but yes kind of configured which I can change at any time based on scalability.

Comment: ok I'll type up a possible answer now

Comment: Parallel processing means crunching a lot of data using as many cores as possible. You can do that with `Parallel.ForEach`. What you posted though shows processing incoming messages. That's the job of ActinBlock<T> or System.Threading.Channels

Comment: Thanks Topher that will be great. Panagiotis Yes I need to process different incoming messages but simultanously for better processing.

Comment: @Topher: Anything from you?

Comment: Ah Sorry @RhettLink I got pulled into something last night just after I started and when I got back and saw the `ActionBlock` answer I thought your problem would be solved :(. I take it you would like another suggestion other than the existing answer? I'll try get one up just now

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for will result in quite a large sample. I'm trying just to demonstrate how you would do this with `ActionBlock<T>`. There's still a lot of unknowns so I left the sample as skeleton you can build off. In the sample the `ActionBlock` will handle and process in parallel all your messages as they're received from your messaging system

```
public class Processor
{
    private readonly IMessagingSystem _messagingSystem;
    private readonly ActionBlock<Message> _handler;
    private bool _pollForMessages;

    public Processor(IMessagingSystem messagingSystem)
    {
        _messagingSystem = messagingSystem;
        _handler = new ActionBlock<Message>(msg => Process(msg), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 //or any configured value
        });
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        _pollForMessages = true;
        while (_pollForMessages)
        {
            var msg = await _messagingSystem.ReceiveMessageAsync();
            await _handler.SendAsync(msg);
        }

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _pollForMessages = false;
    }

    private void Process(Message message)
    {
        //handle message
    }
}
```

[More Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-2.2)

[And Ideas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-messages-to-and-read-messages-from-a-dataflow-block)

Comment: What is Start and inside that RecieveMessageSync and SendAsync methods doing and from where being called?

Comment: `Start` is just a loop to poll for messages received from a fictional message queue, since I don't have whatever mq you may be using. `ReceiveMessageAsync` returns a message from the mq. [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync?view=netcore-2.2) sends a message asynchronously to the `ActionBlock` for processing.

Comment: In my Process method above I am already receiving messages in the form of Message class structure after some fixed interval which works on a callback mechanism should I add the Action Block implementation for parallel processing inside the method after receiving the message?

Comment: No, the `ActionBlock` would replace the callback mechanism and handles processing the messages. You would then deliver messages, using `SendAsync`, to the `ActionBlock` directly on each interval. The `Subscriber` portion stays the same, subscribe to a message, poll on an interval and deliver the message. It's just how and where the message is delivered that changes.

Comment: In general the `Processor` does a similar job as your `Subscriber`. But instead of a callback to the processing method it delivers the message internally to an `ActionBlock` that processes the message.

Comment: Actually I have to use Subscriber-only which in turn uses Kafka to pick messages. So then basically I have to figure out parallel processing around that only.

Comment: Are you saying `Subscriber` is not a class you control?

Comment: Yes this class is being implemented by someone else where callback is implemented using Timer class to push message to my Class on which I want to apply parallel processing. So basically I am using this class in my project which is giving me message after the intervals. Callback method is also implemented in that external class and first parameter is the action which is Process method in my class.

Comment: Ok you should put those details in your OP: Kafka, you don't control subscriber etc. That way others can better help you out.

Comment: But cant we async/parallel the process in Process method after receiving the message from the subscriber?

Comment: Yes you can use the `ActionBlock` there as well, once you have a message just send it to the block and it will handle running everything incoming in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry I'm short on time but here's the general idea/skeleton of what I was thinking as an alternative.

If I'm honest though I think the `ActionBlock<T>` is the better option as there's just so much done for you, with the only limit being that you can't dynamically scale the amount of work it will do it once, although I think the limit can be quite high. If you get into doing it this way you could have more control or just have a kind of dynamic amount of tasks running but you'll have to do a lot of things manually, e.g if you want to limit the amount of tasks running at a time, you'd have to implement a queueing system (something ActionBlock handles for you) and then maintain it. I guess it depends on how many messages you're receiving and how fast your process handles them.

You'll have to check it out and think of how it could apply to your direct use case as I think some of the details area a little sketchily implemented on my side around the concurrentbag idea.

So the idea behind what I've thrown together here is that you can start any number of tasks, or add to the tasks running or cancel tasks individually by using the collection.

The main thing I think is just making the method that the Callback runs fire off a thread that does the work, instead of subscribing within a separate thread.

I used `Task.Factory.StartNew` as you did, but stored the returned Task object in an object (`TaskInfo`) which also had it's CancellationTokenSource, it's Id (assigned externally) as properties, and then added that to a collection of `TaskInfo` which is a property on the class this is all a part of:

**Updated** - to avoid this being too confusing i've just updated the code that was here previously.

You'll have to update bits of it and fill in the blanks in places like with whatever you have for my `HeartbeatController`, and the few events that get called because they're beyond the scope of the question but the idea would be the same.

```
    public class TaskContainer
{
    private ConcurrentBag<TaskInfo> Tasks;
    public TaskContainer(){
        Tasks = new ConcurrentBag<TaskInfo>();
    }


//entry point
//UPDATED
public void StartAndMonitor(int processorCount)
{

        for (int i = 0; i <= processorCount; i++)
        {
            Processor task = new Processor(ProcessorId = i);
            CreateProcessorTask(task);
        }
        this.IsRunning = true;
        MonitorTasks();
}

private void CreateProcessorTask(Processor processor)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Task taskInstance = Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => processor.Start(cancellationTokenSource.Token)
    );
    //bind status update event
    processor.ProcessorStatusUpdated += ReportProcessorProcess;

    Tasks.Add(new ProcessorInfo()
    {
        ProcessorId = processor.ProcessorId,
        Task = taskInstance,
        CancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource
    });

}

//this method gets called once but the HeartbeatController gets an action as a param that it then
//executes on a timer. I haven't included that but you get the idea

//This method also checks for tasks that have stopped and restarts them if the manifest call says they should be running.
//Will also start any new tasks included in the manifest and stop any that aren't included in the manifest.
internal void MonitorTasks()
    {
        HeartbeatController.Beat(() =>
        {
            HeartBeatHappened?.Invoke(this, null);
            List<int> tasksToStart = new List<int>();

            //this is an api call or whatever drives your config that says what tasks must be running.
            var newManifest = this.GetManifest(Properties.Settings.Default.ResourceId);

            //task Removed Check - If a Processor is removed from the task pool, cancel it if running and remove it from the Tasks List.
            List<int> instanceIds = new List<int>();
            newManifest.Processors.ForEach(x => instanceIds.Add(x.ProcessorId));
            var removed = Tasks.Select(x => x.ProcessorId).ToList().Except(instanceIds).ToList();

            if (removed.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var extaskId in removed)
                {
                    var task = Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessorId == extaskId);
                    task.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
                }
            }

            foreach (var newtask in newManifest.Processors)
            {
                var oldtask = Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessorId == newtask.ProcessorId);
                //Existing task check
                if (oldtask != null && oldtask.Task != null)
                {
                    if (!oldtask.Task.IsCanceled && (oldtask.Task.IsCompleted || oldtask.Task.IsFaulted))
                    {
                        var ex = oldtask.Task.Exception;

                        tasksToStart.Add(oldtask.ProcessorId);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else //New task Check                       
                    tasksToStart.Add(newtask.ProcessorId);


            }

            foreach (var item in tasksToStart)
            {
                var taskToRemove = Tasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessorId == item);
                if (taskToRemove != null)
                    Tasks.Remove(taskToRemove);

                var task = newManifest.Processors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessorId == item);
                if (task != null)
                {
                    CreateProcessorTask(task);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

//UPDATED
public class Processor{

private int ProcessorId;
private Subsriber<Message> subsriber;

public Processor(int processorId) => ProcessorId = processorId;

public void Start(CancellationToken token)
{
    Subsriber<Message> subsriber = new Subsriber<Message>()
    {
        Interval = 1000
    };

    subsriber.Callback(Process, m => m != null);
}

private void Process()
{
    //do work
}
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea of how else you can approach your problem and that I didn't miss the point :).

---

**Update**

To use events to update progress or which tasks are processing, I'd extract them into their own class, which then has subscribe methods on it, and when creating a new instance of that class, assign the event to a handler in the parent class which can then update your UI or whatever you want it to do with that info.

So the content of `Process()` would look more like this:

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processor.ProcessMessage(cancellationTokenSource.CancellationToken));

    processor.StatusUpdated += ReportProcess;
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my latest code what I am doing. In that I am creating multiple tasks in this case 5 which I guess u havent done in your code. Can u please take a look in that as well and share your feedback? In that updated code the only thing I am not able to do to find which task id is currently processing. Can you also add the multiple tasks functionality how we can implement in your code as well ?

Comment: @RhettLink In my example it would be creating a new task everytime the `Callback` method fires, so there would be as many as needed for the amount of Messages received. If you need to get information out of a task, I've found that using events works quite well. I'll update my question with an example of that.

Comment: although I think if you're just spawning a new `Task` for each CallBack call of process, you know which ones are running because run until they complete their Processing of the message and then complete.

Comment: But I also want the ability to create how many number of tasks I can create so that I can scale up or down at any time. Just using the Task.Factory.StartNew will not give me that capability. And I dont want create task for each call back because that will create task each time new message is in queue. I should have configured no. of tasks so if one task is working the next message should process on the next task.

Comment: ok, I understand now. i'll update my answer at some point today but am at work so will be when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank u very much you can post whenever u will get the time.

Comment: Did you get the chance?

Comment: also note that the processerId is externally controlled, and that's what is used to manage what task is doing what.

Comment: I am actually confused with  new code. My current implementation is new message will come to the Process method  as a parameter only when the earlier message completed the execution logic in the same Process method only then again call back mechanism will be called and therefore new message will come. Now this process will take time because we have to wait for the current message to complete and then to start the execution of new message. Now here what I wanted to create multiple parallel tasks and each task will have one message and each task will execute the logic of Process method.

Comment: And even if one task took time but other task can complete the same execution in parallel and then the completed task can pick another one  and so on. So multiple tasks can pick multiple messages and do parallel execution of the logic in Process Method. So basically the starting method is Process method around which I have to create parallel execution.

Comment: @RhettLink okay i've updated it again to make it a bit clearer. I'm sure this is doing what you want. The `StartAndMonitor()` method gets a number of tasks to run, and starts them by calling the `CreateProcessorTask` method. In that method it creates a task, which calls a method on the `Processor` class, `Start()`. Start then starts the subscriber and callback to Process within that `Processor` instance which is running in it's own task.

Comment: I dont what is the use of monitor method but cant we know at the execution of Process method which task id is doing the execution for that particular message at that moment for logging purposes?

Comment: @RhettLink you can raise an event from the Processor in a task that includes that information or whatever information you like, like the ProcessorId. The montitor method just restarts any tasks that have thrown an exception, as well as stopping ones that are running or starting new ones as per your scaling requirement.

Comment: I am able to create multiple tasks but lets suppose the way u have created one task and then u are calling Start method in which we have call back and then in turn it called the process method. Now my debug is at process method at that time I still cant know the task id which is doing the processing.

Comment: So basically everytime Process method is called from the call back at that time I should know which task id picked up or processing  the message.

Comment: @RhettLink Using Events will do that for you. Just create a custom event on the Container class, subscribe to it when you create the `Processor` class like I did with this line ` processor.ProcessorStatusUpdated += ReportProcessorProcess;` and raise that event when the subscriber receives a callback. You can create your own `EventArgs` object which you can populate with whatever data you want including the taskId.

Comment: But this will be done on first time in the windows service when we are creating tasks let us suppose 5 for the first time. After that we will create tasks it will be just callback sendind new messages to those 5 tasks.

Comment: Event raising is fine but still my confusion is I raised the task, called the Start method and then call back. Same thing for let suppose 5 times which means 5 threads. Let us suppose then there is no message so call back will not call Process method and when there is a message how can I know which Task Id picked up the message?

Comment: @RhettLink Your tasks need to enter into some kind of loop that you use to check if a message has come in, so maybe, something like Process gets the message and stores it in a property on the class, your process Checks every 10 seconds (or whatever you want) if that property has a value, if it does it executes your code, if it doesn't it sleeps again. 
And the easiest way I can think of for the task ID can be done by giving the `Processor` class an ID when you create it initially, it can be as simple as 1-5, then when your class starts work it raises the event with that

Comment: ID in the EventArgs which the handler then inspects and that's how you'll know which one is working on a message.

Comment: I tried that I am getting all the messages in only one task id.